# Configuration Error while parsing web.config

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am facing a parsing error of web.config while run the my asp.net application in server. The error is following:

Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Source Error:

```
<providers>
    <clear/>
    <add connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" name="MySqlRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.6.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
</providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: That's not close to enough information I'm afraid.  Try including the "Source Error" for a start

Comment: @Simon the source error was in the question, just hiding as markup because it wasn't formatted as code :(

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your website is trying to connect to the MySQL Server instance referenced in the `LocalMySqlServer` connection string and failing - are the details for this server correctly configured on the environment, and can the web server talk to it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Like Zhaph has stated, there could be something wrong with your connection string settings. Should look something like this in your Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=root; password=password;Persist Security Info=True;database=aspmysql"
         providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and then:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySqlRoleProvider">    
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"
             applicationName="/" name="MySqlRoleProvider"
             type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"
             autogenerateschema="true" />
      </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/788357/How-to-set-up-application-using-ASP-NET-Identity-w) to see if it may help you connect your ASP application to MySql.